# Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, internal

When i visit a sub folder on my server i am getting the following error.

> The server encountered an internal
> error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
> administrator, webmaster@bakasura.in
> and inform them of the time the error
> occurred, and anything you might have
> done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
> be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server
> Error error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to
> handle the request. Apache/2.2.17
> (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.7a
> mod_auth_passthrough/2.1
> mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
> PHP/5.2.16 Server at bakasura.in Port
> 80

i dont have a .htaccess in that folder nor in the root directory. Any idea how i can solve this ?

http://bakasura.in/hmv/

**Error LOG**

```
[date] [error] [client 117.192.124.74] File does not exist: /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml
[date] [error] [client 117.192.124.74] File does not exist: /home/bakasura/public_html/html
[date] [error] [client 117.192.124.74] File does not exist: /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml
[date] [error] [client 117.192.124.74] File does not exist: /home/bakasura/public_html/html
[date] [error] [client 117.192.124.74] File does not exist: /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml
[date] [error] [client 117.192.124.74] File does not exist: /home/bakasura/public_html/html
```

> [date] [error]
> [client 122.167.73.182] File does not
> exist:
> /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml
>
> [date] [error]
> [client 122.167.73.182] File does not
> exist:
> /home/bakasura/public_html/favicon.ico
>
> [date] [error]
> [client 122.167.73.182] File does not
> exist:
> /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml
>
> [date] [error]
> [client 122.167.73.182] File does not
> exist:
> /home/bakasura/public_html/favicon.ico
>
> [date] [error]
> [client 180.234.85.76] File does not
> exist:
> /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml
>
> [date] [error]
> [client 180.234.85.76] File does not
> exist:
> /home/bakasura/public_html/favicon.ico
>
> [date] [error]
> [client 180.234.85.76] File does not
> exist:
> /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml
>
> [date] [error]
> [client 180.234.85.76] File does not
> exist:
> /home/bakasura/public_html/favicon.ico

Comment: What CHMOD settings do you have on the sub-folders?

Comment: Do you still get the `500` error after this? `echo 'fail' > /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml`

Comment: these errors seems irrelevant. no `hmv` in these lines.

Comment: @Col i renamed the html folder to hmv to test.

Comment: @Harsha I do not understand your problem then.

Comment: I have the feeling this is not the correct error log. Could it be that you have another one, maybe on a per-domain basis?

Comment: i deleted the folder and created another on http://bakasura.in/gaa/ and it works now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the entire path to `/home/bakasura/public_html/html` must be accessible.

That is, `/home/bakasura` should also have chmod a+x (execute, not read) permissions otherwise Apache can't even enter `/home/bakasura/public_html`.

I would ensure that all directories in the path have at least `chmod a+x`, and that both `public_html` and `public_html/html` contain an index.html which is `chmod a+r`.

Comment: i deleted the folder and created another on bakasura.in/gaa and it works now :P

Answer (score 1):

> **More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

Comment: i checked it. nothing in there. i am using cpanel. any other way to debug it ?

Comment: [Sun Apr 03 06:13:32 2011] [error] [client 117.192.124.74] File does not exist: /home/bakasura/public_html/404.shtml
[Sun Apr 03 06:13:32 2011] [error] [client 117.192.124.74] File does not exist: /home/bakasura/public_html/html

Comment: @Harsha no, there is no other way. you HAVE to consult error logs.